# Snapshot and Restore without give Permission for Backup Folder in Linux

Tags: linux, curl, elasticsearch

I need a elastic search backup in Linux and if i given to permission for that backup folder, repository it would be created.

- with create and give permission to backup folder.

  - `mkdir /home/user/ES`
  - `chmod 777 /home/user/ES`
  - Query : `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_snapshot/myback -d '{"type":"fs","settings":{"location":"/home/user/ES","compress":true}}'`
  - Response : `{ acknowledge : true }...`
  - snapshot and restore works fine, But
- with out create backup folder(`/home/user/ES`) and give permission to that folder it shows error message

  - Query : `curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_snapshot/myback -d '{"type":"fs","settings":{"location":"/home/user/ES","compress":true}}'`
  - Response :

    `{"error":"RepositoryException[[myback] failed to create repository]; nested: CreationException[Guice creation errors:\n\n1) Error injecting constructor, org.elasticsearch.common.blobstore.BlobStoreException: Failed to create directory at [/home/bigdata/ES]\n  at org.elasticsearch.repositories.fs.FsRepository.<init>(Unknown Source)\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.fs.FsRepository\n  while locating org.elasticsearch.repositories.Repository\n\n1 error]; nested: BlobStoreException[Failed to create directory at [/home/bigdata/ES]]; ","status":500}`

I need without create backup folder, and without give permisson for that folder.

please give as a possible solution..

Comment: For me it's not working even creating the folder and giving permissions…